# No output showed in terminal after running C++ file in VsCode

Tags: c++, terminal

After running my C++ file in the VS Code terminal, the output doesn't show up. I tried saving a couple of times, but that didn't change anything
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int name;
name = 5;
cout << "Hello world\n";
return 0;
}


C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\c++> g++ firstfile.cpp

C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\c++>
```

**These above are the commands that I use**

Comment: Did you compile your code?

Comment: Can you show the commands you are using in the terminal?

Comment: I'm just starting out with C++, I don't know what that means but I know the difference between an interpreter and a compiler. However i ran .exe file and it works, but when I try it on my terminal it doesn't. Also I have this weird problem with that terminal that when I open it, it's blank but when I hit enter it shows them. Do you know why?

Comment: `g++ firstfile.cpp` only *compiles* your program into an executable. You still have to *run* the exe file that was produced. Also, printing a `\n` character does not guarantee that output is flushed to the OS. use `cout << endl;` to newline AND flush.